# Searching for key/value pair in Collection, return all values in that Collection if successfully matched

Tags: java, collections

My last attempt was poorly explained, so recreated with hopefully a clearer explanation.

I have a Collection that has the following data structure.

```
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> currentHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    currentHashMap.put("id","12345");
    currentHashMap.put("firstName","John");
    currentHashMap.put("lastName","Doe");

    haystack.add(currentHashMap);
```

*repeat for roughly 250,000 more entries

I need to search the HashMaps within each list entry, check if the key exists, and if it has the corresponding value. If it does, I want to return all the values in that particular hashmap

This is the code that I'm currently using.

```
private TreeSet<String> searchWithinCollection(List<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> haystack, String needle, String needleKey) {

    TreeSet<String> returnValueSet = new TreeSet<>();

    for (LinkedHashMap<String, String> mappedData : haystack) {
                  System.out.println(mappedData.values());
        for (Entry<String, String> specificData : mappedData.entrySet()) {
            if (needleKey.equals(specificData.getKey()) && needle.equals(specificData.getValue())) {
                //where I want to collect the values within the current hashmap, as it's satisfied the search criteria
                                   //the current code would only return the current key/balue pair, even if all values were collected outside the for loop. Instead, I'd want to collect "12345", "John", "Doe" if needleKey = id and needle = 12345.
            }
        }
    }

    return returnValueSet;
}
```

What I'd want is if a key in the current collection equaled "id", and it's value equaled "12345", then I could returned all values within that particular collection (and to use the example above, would be "12345", "John", "Doe"). 
The best I can do is return the first key/value, which isn't very helpful obviously. Attempting to capture all values in mappedData outside the second for loop brought no result (either with creating a new instance of a Collection, clone, or what have you.). I also found nothing that could manually advance the pointer in the for each loop to manually capture all values in the Collection.

EDIT: If it helps, where there is a System.out.println(mappedData.values()); I can get the values I'm expecting, but only the id in the example is return if values() is accessed within the if statement.

Answer (score 4):

You should not iterate over all the entries in a hashmap (currently, the loop `for (Entry<String, String> specificData : mappedData.entrySet())` in your code. This defeats the purpose of maintaining a hashmap.

Instead, the inner loop should become

```
String potentialNeedle = mappedData.get(needleKey);
if (needle.equals(potentialNeedle))
    returnValueSet.addAll(mappedData.values());
```

Comment: I don't think that's working as intended. Just tested it on my code and it return the needle value, but that's it. The matching data for firstName and lastName (to use the above data structure) isn't returned.

Comment: It is, trust them. Check if `containsKey` is true. If not, you don't have to search further, continue with next map. If true, `get( needleKey )` the value and check if it's equal the desired value. If yes, `addAll( mappedData.values() )`. Much faster than iterating (at least for bigger maps - if all your maps only contain three values, it's pretty much meaningless). But of course you'll end up with a set of Strings, whatever you need that for...

Comment: @canadiancreed - added the line where all values get added to the set, as pointed out by Florian. Please check if the elements are actually present in the haystack.

Comment: @ChthonicProject They are, but I'm thinking the passed collection itself might have issues with the format. Smaller sample Collections seem to be working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the map as if it was a list of entries, which completely defeats the purpose of a map: quickly access to a value for a given key:

```
for (Map<String, String> mappedData : haystack) {
    String value = mappedData.get(needleKey);
    if (needle.equals(value)) {
        returnValueSet.addAll(mappedData.values());
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly still having the same problem. I can get the id that I searched for, but not the other data that is within that map.

Comment: `returnValueSet.addAll ( mappedData.values());` What's the problem?

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz returnValueSet.addAll ( mappedData.values()); unfortunately only returns the id value found, as opposed to all values in mappedData (which for this example are "12345", "John", "Doe")

Comment: Something is wrong in your code. What I posted works fine. See https://ideone.com/ldnGNF. If you want help finding the bug, do as I just did: post a complete minimal reproducing example.

Comment: @JBNizet Tried out your code both isolated and within my environment and it failed on mine, but I'm thinking there's something wonky possibly with the data being searched as the rest is checking out as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should take redesign in account to improve performance. it could be smart to have a map for each field you want to search. instead of your haystack create your data-structure like that:

```
public class PersonDataManager {
    private final Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> baseData;
    private final Map<String, List<Integer>> firstNameLookupMap;
    private final Map<String, List<Integer>> lastNameLookupMap;


    public PersonDataManager(){
        this.baseData = new HashMap<>();
        this.firstNameLookupMap = new HashMap<>();
        this.lastNameLookupMap = new HashMap<>();
    }


    public void addPerson(Integer id, String firstName, String lastName){
        //try to find existing person to update:
        Map<String, String> personMap = baseData.get(id);
        if(personMap == null){
            personMap = new HashMap<>();
            baseData.put(id, personMap);
        }
        personMap.put("firstName", firstName);
        personMap.put("lastName", lastName);

        //add to lookup-maps
        addLookupName(firstNameLookupMap, id, firstName);
        addLookupName(lastNameLookupMap, id, lastName);
    }


    private static void addLookupName(Map<String, List<Integer>> nameMap, Integer id, String name){
        //get existing list of the name:
        List<Integer> idList = nameMap.get(name);
        if(idList == null){
            idList = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        if(!idList.contains(id)){
            idList.add(id);
        }
    }


    private List<Map<String, String>> searchByName(Map<String, List<Integer>> nameMap, String name){
        List<Integer> matchingIds = nameMap.get(name);
        List<Map<String, String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        if(matchingIds != null){
            for(Integer id : matchingIds){
                result.add(searchById(id));
            }
        }

        return result;
    }


    public Map<String, String> searchById(Integer id){
        return baseData.get(id);
    }


    public List<Map<String, String>> searchByFirstName(String name){
        return searchByName(firstNameLookupMap, name);
    }


    public List<Map<String, String>> searchByLastName(String name){
        return searchByName(lastNameLookupMap, name);
    }
}
```

This way you can easily get a hashmap of a person using its id. if you need to search by firstname or lastname you can utilize the additional maps to get the matching person-ids. hope this helps

EDIT: Just implemented a class which does exactly what i think you might need. have fun ;)

Comment: It does thank you. Based on previous answers I'm thinking its more an initial structure issues as opposed to code itself